# Add value to result's score in Solr

Tags: solr, edismax

I use Solr (edismax) to search "products".

When I search for some products I get the results with their scores, but I want to add the value of a product field to this score (at search time).

For example:

> For this solr result:
>   Product 1 (field: 0.05) -> Score: 1.5
>   Product 2 (field: 0.30) -> Score: 1.3
>   Product 3 (field: 0.35) -> Score: 1.3
>
> I want to get this:
>   Product 3 (field: 0.35) -> Score: 1.3+0.35 = 1.65
>   Product 2 (field: 0.30) -> Score: 1.3+0.30 = 1.60
>   Product 1 (field: 0.25) -> Score: 1.5+0.05 = 1.55

Can I do this? I tried to use the "bf" option, but it returns a different value of the expected sum.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this plugin to customize solr scores (CustomScoreQuery)

http://spykem.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/plug-in-external-score-to-solr.html